# twitter status updates from command line (via cURL)

Tags: curl

Based on some samples: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/176/update-twitter-via-curl

I'm trying to update my twitter status from command line (via cURL), but always get error. 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
curl -u <anonymized> -d status="#curl test" -d source="cURL" https://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
Enter host password for user '<anonymized>':
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
  <error code="34">Sorry, that page does not exist</error>
</errors>
```

Or possibly, do you have an alternative solution for this (maybe not over cURL)?

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to update twitter from a script or something?

Comment: well, the goal is to do so via linux command line

Comment: I think my one liner answer should suffice for your needs.

Comment: The closest thing to curl for the Twitter API is twurl - OAuth-enabled curl for the Twitter API - I explained it in [**this answer**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42052/how-to-tweet-using-terminal/288470#288470) in more detail. This question is closed so I can't post an answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you grab the perl script [`TTYtter`](http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/) you can make a post from the command line:

```
perl TTYtter -status="Hello World from Linux Shell #bash"
```

Run `TTYtter` once without any switches to setup the OAuth.

Comment: No prob! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

As I said previously on comments, the Twitter OAuth API don't allow the use of POST for updating/tweeting status of Twitter accounts.

Your best bet is using one of the libraries already developed in most of the common languages that are [included here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries), or creating an implementation yourself.

List of twitter libraries: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries